# How to iterate over objects to get different result?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Below is the array of objects and im getting new array that consists of objects having captain name and scores from different rounds but its same captain in all of the array instead what i want is new array with captain name and their scores but my code only gives same results of one captain i dont know why its happening ofcourse there's something wrong im doing but i cant figure it out i want new array with captain name and their scores as object. No same captains having same records over and over again.

```
let data = [{
game_name: "test101"
players_info: {captain: "john", stage_name: "fun fin fo", team_members: "John,Jane,jaden"}
response: "this is one response"
round_num: "1"
score: "1"}
,{game_name: "test101"
players_info: {captain: "B", stage_name: "dssd", team_members: "01,02,03,05"}
response: "another test response....!!!"
round_num: "3"
score: "0"},
{game_name: "test101"
players_info: {captain: "B", stage_name: "baj", team_members: "S"}
response: "He is just gorgeous "
round_num: "1"
score: "6"}
,
{game_name: "test101"
players_info: {captain: "B", stage_name: "fun fin fo", team_members: "Its Just Me and myself :)"}
response: "Thats the same joke we had last week"
round_num: "2"
score: "4"}]
let scores = {};
   let new_arr = [];
   var counter = 0;
   for (let i = 0; i < current_data.length; i++) {
     for (let x = current_data.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
       if (
         current_data[x].players_info.captain ===
         current_data[i].players_info.captain
       ) {
         scores['captain'] = current_data[x].players_info.captain;
         scores[current_data[x].round_num] = current_data[x].score;
    
       }   
     }
     new_arr.push({ score: scores });
   }
   console.log(new_arr);


(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
score: {1: "6", 2: "4", 3: "0", captain: "B"}
__proto__: Object
1:
score: {1: "6", 2: "4", 3: "0", captain: "B"}
__proto__: Object
2:
score: {1: "6", 2: "4", 3: "0", captain: "B"}
__proto__: Object
3:
score: {1: "6", 2: "4", 3: "0", captain: "B"}
__proto__: Object
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was adding the same captain because you set the value of score once and never reset it.

The code now adds the score of each unique captain into the array.

```
let data = [
    {
        game_name: "test101",
        players_info: {
            captain: "john",
            stage_name: "fun fin fo",
            team_members: "John,Jane,jaden"
        },
        response: "this is one response",
        round_num: "1",
        score: "1"
    },
    {
        game_name: "test101",
        players_info: {
            captain: "A",
            stage_name: "dssd",
            team_members: "01,02,03,05"
        },
        response: "another test response....!!!",
        round_num: "3",
        score: "0",
    },
    {
        game_name: "test101",
        players_info: {
            captain: "B",
            stage_name: "baj",
            team_members: "S"
        },
        response: "He is just gorgeous ",
        round_num: "1",
        score: "6",
    },
    {
        game_name: "test101",
        players_info: {
            captain: "C",
            stage_name: "fun fin fo",
            team_members: "Its Just Me and myself :)"
        },
        response: "Thats the same joke we had last week",
        round_num: "2",
        score: "4",
    },
    {
        game_name: "new game",
        players_info: {
            captain: "john",
            stage_name: "fun fin fo",
            team_members: "Its Just Me and myself :)"
        },
        response: "Thats the same joke we had last week",
        round_num: "2",
        score: "4",
    }
];

let scores = {};
let new_arr = [];

for ( i=0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
    
    //Check to see if captain already exists to not make a duplicate entry for the same captain.
    let found = false;
    for( x=0; x < new_arr.length; x++ ) {
        if (new_arr[x].score.captain == data[i].players_info.captain) {
            found = true;
            let temp = new_arr[x];
            temp.score[`Game#${data[i].round_num}`] = data[i].score; //Adding another game entry to the captain.
            new_arr[x]=temp;
        }
    }

    //If the captain doesnt already exist in the new_arr, create a new entry for them.
    if ( found == false ) {
        scores = {}; //Here the captains object is reset.
        scores['captain'] = data[i].players_info.captain;
        scores[`Game#${data[i].round_num}`] = data[i].score;
        new_arr.push({ score: scores });
    }
}

console.log(new_arr);
```

Output for test data where john has two games:

```
[
  { score: { captain: 'john', 'Game#1': '1', 'Game#2': '4' } },
  { score: { captain: 'A', 'Game#3': '0' } },
  { score: { captain: 'B', 'Game#1': '6' } },
  { score: { captain: 'C', 'Game#2': '4' } }
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i see now i forgot to reset the object but it was still holding the value into it.